Intensity outliers in 2D plot (max or min local peaks with high intensity)
I wonder what kind of method better to use to see outliers on z value of 2D plot. For example, I have measurements of x and y values both in range of 1 to 16 with step of 1. Next I calculate how many observations each pair of x and y (x_n, y_n) have. That give me a grid of 16 by 16 with number of observations per pair (z). Because x and y are correlated (~0.5) we expect to see some groups of dots more often presented then others. It happens that in area where few observations expected, many are presented. Some equipment error. What are the best method to find those in large data where grid is not 16 by 16 but 9000 x 9000.
Here is some hard-coded sandbox example:
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Let's make data x, y, z.
# x and y are coordinates similar to matrix coordinate
x = [i for i in range(1, 17) for j in range(16)]
y = list(range(1, 17)) * 16


# z is a set of random integer values in some range
def r_num(base_value: int, n_numbers: int):
    return [random.randint(base_value, base_value + 700) for i in range(n_numbers)]

def z_make():
    _z = ((r_num(2000, 16)) +
         (r_num(2000, 16)) +
         (r_num(2000, 2) + r_num(5000, 12) + r_num(2000, 2)) +
         (r_num(2000, 2) + r_num(5000, 12) + r_num(2000, 2)) +
         (r_num(2000, 2) + r_num(5000, 2) + r_num(7000, 8) + r_num(5000, 2) + r_num(2000, 2)) +
         (r_num(2000, 2) + r_num(5000, 2) + r_num(7000, 1) + r_num(9000, 6) + r_num(7000, 1) + r_num(5000, 2) + r_num(2000, 2)) +
         (r_num(2000, 2) + r_num(5000, 2) + r_num(7000, 1) + r_num(9000, 1) + r_num(10000, 4) + r_num(9000, 1) + r_num(7000, 1) + r_num(5000, 2) + r_num(2000, 2)) +
         (r_num(2000, 2) + r_num(5000, 2) + r_num(7000, 1) + r_num(9000, 1) + r_num(10000, 1) + r_num(16000, 2) + r_num(10000, 1) + r_num(9000, 1) + r_num(7000, 1) + r_num(5000, 2) + r_num(2000, 2)))
    return _z


z1 = z_make()
z2 = z_make()
z2.reverse()
z = z1 + z2

for i in ['x','y','z']:
    print('Len of i:', len(eval(i)))

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z})

# Set some outliers and missing value near outlier
df.loc[(df['x'] == 2) & (df['y'] == 6), 'z'] = 15875
df.loc[(df['x'] == 15) & (df['y'] == 2), 'z'] = 14999
df.loc[(df['x'] == 2) & (df['y'] == 7), 'z'] = None

plt.scatter(df.x, df.y, c=df.z, cmap='viridis', s=100, alpha=0.7)

# Add color bar
plt.colorbar(label='Intensity')

# Set labels and title
plt.xlabel('X Label')
plt.ylabel('Y Label')
plt.show()


So neighboring x and y have value of z much lower then the outliers.
I have been studying KDE, contour and Local Outlier Factor (LOF), but there were not successful. Actually KDE works ok-ish, but bandwidth influence detection of the outliers dramatically. I need to find points where the z value is significantly different from its neighbors’ z values in large scatter-plot.

As this really isn't a programming issue you might get better answers to your question if you repost over at the Cross Validated StackExchange.

I will do so, thanks.

@user24714692 two yellow dots in position (2, 6) and (15, 2)

For each point find the average of its 4 (or maybe 8) neighbours. If it differs from them by more than some specified fraction of the range then replace by that average. This would deal with “occasional” outliers.

Are you interested in controlling similarity of immediate neighbors only ?

@keepAlive not exactly. If some wider area can be used. I suppose KDE use large areas.

What did you do finally ?

@keepAlive My data is continuous. For the question i did some simplification. So in reality i came out with following solution:

I create table with pairwise frequencies like:
x       y     freq/intensity
2.34 3.45 5000
2.34 3.46 5002
2.35 3.44 4895...
Big table.
Put values to a grid. Function look for minimal step and convert continues numbers to integer positions.
For every dot difference or weighted difference with neighbors mean calculated. Neighbors can be of radius 1,2,3...
Should it be called focal outlier approach?
So if dot frequency 5000 but neighbors mean 1000.


Also account for magnitude of change. For example if some dot intensity is 500, but neighbor mean 100, ratio is 5. But difference of 400 is not large for me. However, ratio == 5 also if dot 100 000 and neighbors mean 20 000. That is large.

Why not use spatial weight matrices and confront/compare each of the components of z with their neighbors average ? As follows:
import numpy as np

# Form arrays of interest
x_, y_, z_ = map(
    np.transpose, map(
        np.atleast_2d,
        df[['x', 'y', 'z']].to_numpy().T
    )
)

# Locate `z`'s `nan`s
z_is_nan = np.isnan(z_)
nanmat   = z_is_nan & z_is_nan.T

# Compute the distance matrix, euclidean for p=2
p    = 2.
dx   = x_ - x_.T
dy   = y_ - y_.T
dmat = (dx**p + dy**p)**(1/p)

# Let's focus on, e.g. first order neighbors, setting `k` accordingly
k              = 2**(1/p)  # Equivalent to Moore's neighbors when `p=2`
dmat[dmat > k] = np.inf
dmat[nanmat]   = np.inf  # Target holes in the grid.
emat           = np.exp(-dmat)

# Let's compute the weight matrix, i.e. `emat`'s row-stochastic counterpart
wmat = emat / np.where(
    _sum := emat.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True), _sum, 1.
)

# Compute spatial (weighted) averages, arbitrarily substituting 
# `nan`s for `z`'s average. Replace `nan`s by something more extreme
# if you want them to be considered as outliers.
z_µ       = np.where(z_is_nan, np.nanmean(z_), z_)
df['z_k'] = z_k = wmat.dot(z_µ)

# Let's compute z-scores inspired statistics
dz_k    = z_k - z_µ  # deltas of interest.
dz_k_nz = (dz_k  - dz_k .mean()) / dz_k .std(ddof=1)  # centered and reduced version of `dz_k`.
df['s'] = dz_k_nz  # Where `s` stands for "score"

Let's have a look around where you have injected the outliers.
>>> df.iloc[[19, 21, 22, 23, 224, 225, 226], :]
      x  y        z          z_k         s
19    2  4   2644.0  3148.850916  0.470971
21    2  6  15875.0  7310.790530 -8.212291  # <---
22    2  7      NaN  5367.282896  0.260845
23    2  8   2070.0  3247.581469  1.115083
224  15  1   2455.0  4132.371367  1.593612
225  15  2  14999.0  6252.208638 -8.387106  # <---
226  15  3   2426.0  4251.586363  1.735522

In this instance, (spatially dissimilar) zs are identified by (absolute) great (negative) scores

Any question @Zoomman ?

Thank you for the answer. I see that method is sensitive to 0 or nan value, if some are missing. But for basic approach works good! I made more explicit question here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/647184/intensity-outliers-in-2d-plot

You are welcome @Zoomman. Where are the 0s or nans likely to occur ? Within the z vector, aren't they ? Do not hesitate to enrich your example with such events.

I edited code a bit, to make data look more realistic

@Zoomman see update regarding the ability to process 0/nans. Also, take a look at a statistically enhanced version of the above answer.

This problem can be solved using a O(N ^ 2) algorithm, N being the size of grid.
We check the Moore's neighbors to see if the value of the cell is much higher, as compared to other cells.
import numpy as np


def find_higher_points(G, threshold):
    rows, cols = G.shape
    moore = ((1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 0), (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1))
    res = []
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            curr = G[i, j]
            neighbors = []
            for dx, dy in moore:
                if 0 <= i + dx < rows and 0 <= j + dy < cols:
                    neighbors.append(G[i + dx, j + dy])

            if curr > threshold * np.mean(neighbors):
                res.append((i, j))

    return res


z = []
z = (z + [2000] * 16 + [2000] * 16 +
     ([2000] * 2 + [5000] * 12 + [2000] * 2) +
     ([2000] * 2 + [5000] * 12 + [2000] * 2) +
     ([2000] * 2 + [5000] * 2 + [7000] * 8 + [5000] * 2 + [2000] * 2) +
     ([2000] * 2 + [5000] * 2 + [7000] + [9000] * 6 + [7000] + [5000] * 2 + [2000] * 2) +
     ([2000] * 2 + [5000] * 2 + [7000] + [9000] + [10000] * 4 + [9000] + [7000] + [5000] * 2 + [2000] * 2) +
     ([2000] * 2 + [5000] * 2 + [7000] + [9000] + [10000] + [16000] * 2 + [10000] + [9000] + [7000] + [5000] * 2 + [2000] * 2))
z1 = z.copy()
z1.reverse()
Y = z + z1

G_size = 16
K = [[Y[j * G_size + i] for j in range(G_size)] for i in range(G_size)]

K[2][6] = 15000
K[15][2] = 15000

K = np.array(K)


threshold = 2
print(find_higher_points(K, threshold))



Prints
[(2, 6), (15, 2)]


Note

No point in the border should be part of the output. Right?

The Moore neighborhood.


None Values

If you have None or other values, you can set it to a specific value (e.g., -1, 0, -math.inf) or add other checks in your algorithm.

Code (1000 * 1000 Grid)
import numpy as np


def find_higher_points(G, threshold):
    rows, cols = G.shape
    moore = ((1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 0), (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1))
    res = []
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            if G[i][j] is None:
                continue
            curr = G[i, j]
            neighbors = []
            for dx, dy in moore:
                if 0 <= i + dx < rows and 0 <= j + dy < cols:
                    nei = G[i + dx, j + dy]
                    if nei is not None:
                        neighbors.append(nei)

            if neighbors and curr > threshold * np.mean(neighbors):
                res.append((i, j))

    return res


N = 1000
np.random.seed(1)
K = np.random.randint(100, 201, size=(N, N)).astype(object)

for i in range(1, N, 50):
    for j in range(1, N, 50):
        K[i, j] = 500
        K[j, i] = None

threshold = 2
print(find_higher_points(K, threshold))



Partial Prints

[(51, 1), (101, 1), (101, 51), (151, 1), (151, 51), (151, 101), (201,
1), (201, 51), (201, 101), (201, 151), (251, 1), (251, 51), (251,
101), (251, 151), (251, 201), ....


Thank you! Looks interesting. I wonder will it hit an error if some value out of grid is absent. Let's imagine we have pick and 4 out of 8 neighbors. Need to test...

@Zoomman Updated. It works for 1000 * 1000, takes a few seconds. Also added some None values. If you had other "undesired" values, you can filter, alter, etc.
